# Excel 2013: convert text to number

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

I have one column where I've pasted values such as `'$‎1,995.00'`. I want to use this value and make calculations on it.

Here's what I tried in the column next to my data:

```
=RIGHT(L10,8)+0
```

This works. BUT the number of integers in my data cells varies. So when I try `=RIGHT(L10,LEN(L10)-1)+0`, it doesn't work. And I don't understand why.

There has to be a simpler way of doing this.

Comment: Try to multiply it by `1`, it could work, but with the `$` I'm not certain how it'll go.

Answer (score 1):

Try

`=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(L10,"$",""),",","")+0`

This will get rid of '$' & ',' and +0 will convert the resulting to integer/number

Answer (score 1):

The first 'tick' (aka *single quote* or `CHAR(39)`) is being interpreted as a [Range.PrefixCharacter property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.prefixcharacter.aspx). This commonly forces numbers to text and is not displayed. Conversion to a true number will also be hampered by the currency symbol but not by the comma.

For a more universal conversion try one of these,

```
=VALUE(MID(L10, 3, LEN(L10)-3))
=--MID(L10, 3, LEN(L10)-3)
=MID(L10, 3, LEN(L10)-3)*1
=MID(L10, 3, LEN(L10)-3)+0
```